# Command prompt "access denied" error for a simple java program

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I created the source file .java with the following code:

```
// bank.java
// demonstrates basic OOP syntax
// to run this program: C>java BankApp
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class BankAccount
{
private double balance;                   // account balance
public BankAccount(double openingBalance) // constructor
{
balance = openingBalance;
}
public void deposit(double amount)        // makes deposit
{
balance = balance + amount;
}
public void withdraw(double amount)       // makes withdrawal
{
balance = balance - amount;
}
public void display()                     // displays balance
{
System.out.println(“balance=” + balance);
}
}  // end class BankAccount
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class BankApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
BankAccount ba1 = new BankAccount(100.00); // create acct
System.out.print(“Before transactions, “);
ba1.display();                         // display balance
ba1.deposit(74.35);                    // make deposit
ba1.withdraw(20.00);                   // make withdrawal
System.out.print(“After transactions, “);
ba1.display();                         // display balance
}  // end main()
}  // end class BankApp
```

I compiled it using the command "javac" and got two class files - each one for one class.
I try to run it with cmd, but I get the error "access denied" after I type in:

```
C:\new>java -cp <C:\new> BankApp.class
```

After typing in:

```
C:\new>java BankApp.class
```

I get: Error: Could not find or load main class BankApp.class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command

```
C:\new>java -cp <C:\new> BankApp.class
```

attempts to redirect input from `C:\new` and redirect output to `BankApp.class`. In a Windows command prompt (and most other command prompts, for that matter), `<` redirects input and `>` redirects output. Separately, when you're running a Java class, you don't specify the `.class`, you give the *class* name, not the filename.

If your goal is to make sure that the current directory is in the classpath, what you're looking for there is:

```
C:\new>java -cp . BankApp
```

If your goal is to make sure that the directory `c:\new` is in the classpath (even if it isn't the current directory, although it is in your example), what you're looking for there is:

```
C:\new>java -cp c:\new BankApp
```

---

Note that the command you first tried may well have deleted or truncated your `BankApp.class` file, so you may have to recompile it before the above will work.

Answer (score 1):

You just need:

```
java BankApp
```

Or

```
java -cp c:\new BankApp
```

Java takes the name of a *class*, not a *file*... and if you use `<` and `>` that's asking the Windows shell to perform redirection, which you don't want.